# How do I restrict access to Google Compute Engine to only my Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to secure my service on Compute engine so that only my Firebase functions can access it using vpc / firewall rules?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using VPC/Firewalls to secure your GCE instance, you could use [Identity-Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-gce-howto), and have the function [authenticate as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account) using the default service account for Cloud Functions (project_id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com). This is very robust against network changes, and is very flexible..

Comment: It's a good idea, but that "authenticate as a service account" page doesn't have an example for Javascript, which is the only language the cloud functions can use.